# How to add empty new lines in less (log viewer)?

Tags: logs, monitoring, tail, less

When I monitor some log file with `tail -F file.log`, I can press `enter` to add some space between actual log lines and the new ones, for example:

```
some log 1
some log 2
some log 3


some log 4
some log 5
```

But when I monitor some file with `less file.log`, I cannot add such space when I press the `enter` key. How could I add this `tail -F file.log` behavior to `less file.log`?

#### Update

I would not like to edit the log file, I just need to add some spacing on the output while I am reviewing them in realtime (while I run tests on the application). Whether the file is going to be edited or not is irrelevant.

I just would like to use `less` instead of `tail` because `less` is more feature rich as find in buffer, etc.

Comment: I would like to view a log file written in realtime, so opening in a editor is not option. That is why I use `tail -F`.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkfifo fifo
tail -F file.log >fifo &
./script.sh | less
```

with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<fifo

while true; do
        IFS= read -r -u 3 line
        test -n "$line" && echo "$line"
        if read -t 1 dummyline; then
                echo
        fi
done
```

Comment: I think that with this both `./script.sh` and `less` will compete on reading from the tty. Not good. Also, what will happen when the user presses Ctrl-C inside `less` (as when trying to get out of the `F` mode?